# Strange output with tabularx

Tags: tabularx

This code is part of a larger file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,BCOR8mm,final,linktocpage,twoside,open=right,headsepline,a4paper]{scrbook}   
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color}
\usepackage[hang,small]{subfigure}
\usepackage[small,bf]{caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\typearea{10}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{picins,extpic}
\usepackage{booktabs,colortbl,footmisc}
\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{wallpaper,eso-pic,watermark} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx,hhline}



\begin{document}



\begin{center}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \begin{tabularx}{.7\linewidth}{||p{2.363in}*{2}{|r}||}
    \hhline{|t:===:t|}
    \cellcolor{gray!15} \textbf{Lage der Messfl\"ache} & {\cellcolor{gray!15} \textbf{Rechtswert [m]}} & {\cellcolor{gray!15} \textbf{Hochwert [m]}} \\
    \hhline{|:=|=|=:|}
    \cellcolor{gray!15} Das ist ein Test: Was passiert, wenn der Text sehr lange ist?  & 345678.45 & 54346578.88  \\
    \hhline{|b:===:b|}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

Two questions: How can I

- avoid the "X" and "X(0)p"? Both are due tabular.sty (line 119 and 121), I think.
- align the multiline-text?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: line 119 of `tabularx.sty` is `\@tempdimb\maxdimen` why do you think that makes the output you show?

Comment: In my file the lines 119 - 121 are: \newcolumntype{X}{}
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{p{#1}}
\def\TX@newcol{\newcol@{X}[0]}
so I thought that this could be the cause...

Comment: Don't pass the `pdftex` option to any package.

Comment: @Harald something is wrong with your file, they are lines 153-156 so your file is corrupted and missing some lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your MWE I can't reproduce your image (with `X` above table and `X(0)p` before table, Table looks OK.

I wondewr, why you use `tabularx and than define only` p{..}`and`r`type columns? I sugest you to use only`tabular` width specified columns:

```
\documentclass[11pt,BCOR8mm,final,linktocpage,twoside,open=right,headsepline,a4paper]{scrbook}
    %\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    %\usepackage[pdftex]{color}% <-- surplus
    \usepackage[hang,small]{subfigure}
    \usepackage[small,bf]{caption}
    %\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \typearea{10}
    %\usepackage{sidecap}
    %\usepackage{picins,extpic}
    \usepackage{booktabs,colortbl,footmisc}
    %\usepackage{color,xcolor} % <-- surplus
    %\usepackage{wallpaper} % <-- surplus
    \usepackage{fancybox}
    %\usepackage{wallpaper,eso-pic,watermark}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{tabularx,hhline}
    
        \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{||p{2.363in}*{2}{|r}||}
        \hhline{|t:===:t|}
        \cellcolor{gray!15} \textbf{Lage der Messfl\"ache} & {\cellcolor{gray!15} \textbf{Rechtswert [m]}} & {\cellcolor{gray!15} \textbf{Hochwert [m]}} \\
        \hhline{|:=|=|=:|}
        \cellcolor{gray!15} Das ist ein Test: Was passiert, wenn der Text sehr lange ist?  & 345678.45 & 54346578.88  \\
        \hhline{|b:===:b|}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
        \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

or use `tabularx and replace` p{...}`width`X`:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{||X*{2}{|r}||}
    \hhline{|t:===:t|}
    \cellcolor{gray!15} \textbf{Lage der Messfl\"ache} & {\cellcolor{gray!15} \textbf{Rechtswert [m]}} & {\cellcolor{gray!15} \textbf{Hochwert [m]}} \\
    \hhline{|:=|=|=:|}
    \cellcolor{gray!15} Das ist ein Test: Was passiert, wenn der Text sehr lange ist?  & 345678.45 & 54346578.88  \\
    \hhline{|b:===:b|}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

In both example I use the same preamble. In it I mark packages, which you load twice (once is enough) and comment those, which I haven't installed and are not influence on table design. In code I replace `begin{center} ... \end{center}` around table (this is wrong use) width `\centering` command after `\begin{table}`.

To my taste, better result you will obtain with the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,BCOR8mm,final,linktocpage,twoside,open=right,headsepline,a4paper]{scrbook}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[hang,small]{subfigure}
\usepackage[small,bf]{caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\typearea{10}
\usepackage{booktabs,colortbl,footmisc}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,hhline}

\usepackage{siunitx}

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{0.85\textwidth}{||>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X 
                                *{2}{|S[table-format=8.3]}||}
    \hhline{|t:===:t|}
    \cellcolor{gray!15} \textbf{Lage der Messfl\"ache} & {\cellcolor{gray!15} \textbf{Rechtswert [m]}} & {\cellcolor{gray!15} \textbf{Hochwert [m]}} \\
    \hhline{|:=|=|=:|}
    \cellcolor{gray!15} Das ist ein Test: Was passiert, wenn der Text sehr lange ist?  & 345678.45 & 54346578.88  \\
    \hhline{|b:===:b|}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

As you can see, For numbers in last two columns I use `S` type of column provided by (added) package `siunitx`.